# Storing data in sqlite but want to transfer in future to online db? (android)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Hey so I am creating an app that allows people to store a bunch of words, and I am doing it with sqlite. However, in the future I am planning on letting users pay for it to be stored online in my db (mongodb/sql if needed), so the dilemma is how should I structure the future transfer and make it specific to users who have paid accounts, without storing users with unpaid accounts?

Option 1: Use http client for transfers (however, will it be a problem if it is 1,000 of words)? Then, just store accounts for users who are paid only (but then how do I avoid wasting time on requests from non-paid clients)? Also, should I have the db secure (currently did not include prepared statements or anything for sql injections, was planning on it, but was not sure what exactly should be secured against)?

Option 2: If there is a way to somehow send a copy of the db file, if that makes any sense?

I am out of options but let me know basically how I can go about transferring data in the future if it is stored in sqlite and any precautions necessary that can be handled before putting the app out.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a web service that at a minimum does two things:

1. Check purchase against Google Play API
2. If the Google API says valid do database work

If you are not concerned about piracy you can check for purchases via your app, rather than web server, and trust that they are legit.  Then only do an HTTP request if the user has purchases.

To prevent sending large amounts of communication data you can put a timestamp on entries in your SQLite database and only send items for a certain date.